# UML Diagram for program

Tags: uml

I have to complete a program that implements a car Park system.
I started with the UML diagram as I think it is easier for the program to be done after that, but I am a bit stack.
The scenario is:

1. Design  and  implement  a  class  Vehicle  (abstract)  and  the  subclasses  Car,  Van, Motorbike. The classes should include appropriate methods and hold information about the ID plate of the vehicle, the brand of the vehicle and the entry time/date in the parking.

In particular:

•   The  Car  class  should  also  include  appropriate  methods  and  hold  information 
about the number of the doors of the car and the color.
•   The  Van  class  should  also  include  methods  and  information  about  the  cargo 
volume of the van.
  The  class  Motorbike  should  also  have  methods  and  information  about  the  size 
engine of the motorbike.

You  should  implement  a  class  DateTime  to  represent  the  time/date  of  the  entrance  of 
the vehicle in the parking.  Do not use any predefined library.

2. Design and implement a class called MyCarParkManager, which extends the 
   interface   CarParkManager.   MyCarParkManager   maintains   the   list   of   the 
   vehicles currently in the parking.
   The  class  should  display  in  the  console  a  menu  from  which  the  user  can  select  among 
   the following management actions:

•   Add a new vehicle in the parking if there are free lots (considering that the max number  of  lots  is  20)  and  return  the  number  of  the  free  lots  remaining. Consider that a Van occupied 2 lots.  Display a message with the number of free lots or informing that there are no lots available.

•   Delete a vehicle, selecting the ID plate, from the list when the vehicle leaves the car park and return the vehicle instance. Display the type of the vehicle leaving the parking (if it is a car, a van or a motorbike).

•   Print the list of the vehicles currently parked. For each vehicle print the ID plate,  and  the  entry  time  and  the  type  of  vehicle  (if  is  a  car,  a  van  or  a motorbike).  The  list  should  be  ordered  chronologically,  displaying  the  last vehicle entered in the parking as the first in the list.

And this is what I've got so far. [My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y0iC.jpg)

Since class Vehicle is abstract and cannot be instanced, what should I use to create different vehicle objects, might it be an array? And how should the output be changed, I mean depending on what the input is going to be: If it is car, to ask for color also, if it is a van for cargo volume?

Thanks a lot in advance to who take the time to read it and see if this UML seems right.

Comment: Your model is hard to read as it is just a draw (I guess the links are inheritance, what the color code means?). Are there any associations? You should use a real UML modeler. I suggest using https://www.genmymodel.com

Comment: I'm sorry but your diagram has hardly anything in common with UML. You should take any reasonable book about UML and read at least basics. Moreover this page is not about asking if my homework is done correctly. You should ask about specific problems like "I have this relationship, in what direction should be my arrow" and even that only if you really can't find an answer (and you'd really tried). As it's impossible to understand logic when you're that far from UML, I'm not analyzing it at all.

Comment: I'd recommend to read some basic literature about UML and then try again. This has so much in common with UML than paintings from my children with (say) Picasso.

Comment: It is the program that is more important anyway. But I am stack and I supposed that doing a very basic UML would help me to do the program.
Since class Vehicle is abstract and cannot be instanced, what should I use to create different vehicle objects, might it be an array?
And how should the output be changed, I mean depending on what the input is going to be:
If it is car, to ask for color also, if it is a van for cargo volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Analyze the statement

> An important skill that you will start to develop in this module is analyzing a problem statement in order to identify the details needed to develop a solution.In this assignment the first task you should perform is a careful analysis of the problem statement in order to make sure you have all the information to elaborate a solution. Do not make assumption about what is needed! If you are not sure, about the information provided, ask questions.

#### Design a solution:

> The design of your system should be consistent with the Object Oriented principles and easy to understand by an independent programmer.

Source: 5COSC001W Object Oriented Programming - Assignment 1

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering which one should be better - to implement the vehicle as an array or simply creating vehicle objects?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you:

- class: "VehicleCardInfo" for storing cars information and status
- class: RulesForCarPark for validate all data in "VehicleCardInfo"
- vocabulary for: car types e.t.c.

CarParkManager as Actor use UseCase "Managing Cars" for CRUD operation for "VehicleCardInfo" objects.

Maybe we need some rules for people to logging and use this application.

UML diagram maybe easy for above (we don't use associations, use dependency).